# php merge 'subsets' of array in loop

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I'm struggling merging subsets of an array in a loop.

I have a big array that can contain any amount of $data records (depending on the API results)

When I try to merge just 2 'products' subsets this works just fine:

```
$merged=array_merge($data[0][products], $data[1][products]);
```

But since I don't know in advance how many $data records I will end up with I decided to do it in a loop, something like this:

```
foreach ($data as $products) {
$merged=array_merge($merged,$products[products]);
}
```

This doesn't work, I've been playing around with this for a couple of hours, but haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: can you add the line where $merged is declared and initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an ideal situation to use [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) in combination with [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
$merged = call_user_func_array('array_merge', array_column($data, 'products'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this above the `foreach`:

`$merged = array();`

Also I reckon `$data[0][products]` needs to be `$data[0]['products']`.